# How to access Laravel relationship in blade

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

Need help with Laravel 5.4.

I have 2 tables: origins and coffees.

An origin can have many coffees.

In the Origin model I set it up:

```
public function coffee()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Coffee');
}
```

In my controller I have this:

```
$origins = Origin::with('coffee')->get();
```

In my view I need to display all the coffees for each origin, my code:

```
 @foreach($origins as $origin)
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 centered">
                    <h3>{{ $origin->name }}</h3>

                    @foreach($origin->coffee() as $coffee)
                        {{  $coffee->name }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

But nothing is displayed as the coffee name.

I have one record in the coffees table that belongs to origin with id 1.

Why don't I get the coffee's name?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out I needed to remove the brackets from coffee:
foreach($origin->coffee)...